# Bing Maps API URL

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I am currently at the stage of passing a '**quadkey**' to the Bing Maps API to return me the tiles, but i am getting stuck with what URL i pass this to.

Currently my code looks something like:

```
if (zoomLevel < 16 && zoomLevel > 13)
{
    uri = new Uri("??" + qk.Key + ".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

I am wondering am i doing this correctly? I have an API key as well but were does that get used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the Bing Maps controls you don't need to directly access the map tiles as they are already in the map control. Simply change the map type. Which map control are you using?